# About using Selenium in my first android app

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

After finishing my desktop software that use selenium to sendkeys and get a screenshot for the captcha,

i'm trying now to build it for android, but i don't know from where i need to start,

i searched alot about how can i send editText's values that have email,password and captcha to a website

- Do i need to install android-server.apk besides my app ? 
  because the software i built use phantomjs.exe
- i added selenium lib and java-client to `add as library` and sync, but i still can't import the libraries in the main activity, so when i write `WebDriver driver = new AndroidWebDriver(getActivity());` i got an error

> Cannot resolve symbol 'WebDriver'

How can i solve that ?

- Is there's better option than that? i don't want the users to install other app in their devices in order to use the main app